# Docker doesn't install PHP modules

Tags: php, docker

Why are the modules not loaded?

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:5.6-apache

# Install PHP extensions and PECL modules.
RUN buildDeps=" \
        libbz2-dev \
        libmemcached-dev \
        libmysqlclient-dev \
        libsasl2-dev \
    " \
    runtimeDeps=" \
        curl \
        git \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libicu-dev \
        libjpeg-dev \
        libldap2-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libmemcachedutil2 \
        libpng12-dev \
        libpq-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
    " \
    && apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y $buildDeps $runtimeDeps \
    && docker-php-ext-install bcmath bz2 calendar iconv intl mbstring mcrypt mysql mysqli opcache pdo_mysql pdo_pgsql pgsql soap zip \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd \
    && docker-php-ext-configure ldap --with-libdir=lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install ldap \
    && docker-php-ext-install exif \
    && pecl install memcached-2.2.0 redis \
    && docker-php-ext-enable memcached.so redis.so \
    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove $buildDeps \
    && rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && a2enmod rewrite

RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data
RUN usermod -G staff www-data
```

And this is the output from `php -m`:

```
root@3363bf2aa56d:/var/www/html# php -m
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/pdo.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/pdo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xsl.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xsl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[PHP Modules]
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
ereg
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
hash
iconv
intl
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

For example, there is no calendar extension, but it is defined in the Dockerfile itself. Also, exif doesn't appear in the list. Whats wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Solution was, that the php.ini hasn't been updated accordingly.

```
...
extension=gd.so
extension=calendar.so
extension=exif.so
extension=xdebug.so
extension=soap.so
extension=opcache.so
...
```

Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a command in the Dockerfile to activate the extension after building. For example, to enable the calendar extension add:

`RUN php5enmod calendar`